# CSS: hiding a field makes another field disappear

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension to edit some textual fields and I've encountered a bug:
I've to simply hide that "Stato" field so I wrote that CSS code..
[image]
[image]

And that works, but it also hides the first field ("Consulenti"), I've no idea why since they don't share the same data-test-item or stuff like that.
[image]
Do you have any idea why is it happening?
Thanks in advance for you attention and answers!

EDIT: Here's the code of the "Consulenti" field (the purple highlights is there because there's an active function that change the text from "Agenti" to "Consulenti", but the text disappear even if this function is disabled, so I don't think this affects anything)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the same with the id?

Comment: The problem is that the id isn't constant, it chages every once in a while when the page is refreshed

Comment: Can you also show the Consulenti element like you have shown the stato in debugger ?

Comment: I've added the screenshot above! @anurag-sanghvi

Comment: I dont know if its a proper solution but cant you add a similar line of code for Consulenti and set display:block !important; . It would be sort of a hack assuming it works i guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ember1346{
display: none !important;
}
```

Did you try doing it like this?

Comment: Yep but the id changes every once in a while when the page get refreshed, so I can't use the id :/

Comment: Alright. Let's try adding a class 'd-none' to this div and setting display to none in that class? Would that help?